# Add self signed certificate to ubuntu for use with curl

Tags: ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

I'm developing a program where I have a virtual development server that runs with a self signed certificate. My program uses curl to connect to the server and pull information, but needs to do so with SSL.  When I try to connect I get the error "SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK."  When running firefox I can add the certificate to just firefox, but that doesn't help me with curl.  How do I add the certificate for curl to recognize?

curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.15
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz

Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx 64bit

Comment: [cURL: Adding/Installing/Trusting New Self-Signed Certificate](http://turboflash.wordpress.com/2009/06/23/curl-adding-installing-trusting-new-self-signed-certificate/)

Comment: Also see [Use self signed certificate with cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27611193/608639) It is a good, canonical answer. Daniel Stenberg, the author of cURL, answered the question.

Comment: That blog moved. Here's the new URL: [cURL: Adding/Installing/Trusting N Self-Signed Certificate](https://interest.richieteo.com/2009/06/23/curl-adding-installing-trusting-new-self-signed-certificate/)

Answer (score 17):

This is one way that worked for me:

First, get the CA cert from the development domain and save it to a file called 'logfile'. (Assumes port 443 for SSL)

```
openssl s_client -connect xxxxx.com:443 |tee logfile
```

Then, use the --cacert curl option to use the saved certificate file.

```
curl --cacert logfile **THE REST OF YOUR CURL COMMAND**
```

Source:
http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Mind trying on a current version of curl? Also, knowing what commands you used to generate the key may be useful.

Comment: Worked for me using curl version curl 7.81.0 (Release-Date: 2022-01-05)

Answer (score 16):

I'd copy the certificate to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`.

Let me quote the man page for [update-ca-certificates](http://man.he.net/man8/update-ca-certificates):

> Furthermore  all  certificates  with  a  .crt  extension  found   below /usr/local/share/ca-certificates   are   also  included  as  implicitly trusted.

Answer (score 9):

Add your rootCA.pem in `/usr/share/ca-certificates` directory.

After that update your certificates with: `update-ca-certificates --fresh` command.

I just did that, and works fine.

Comment: This would also require appending cert part to `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`, but you shouldn't do that, because it's autogenerated. Add the root PEM file to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` instead.

Answer (score 2):

First, in your Linux, you should add your CERTIFICATE.cert to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`.
After that by adding `--cacert CERTIFICATE.cert`  to your command, curl will automatically use this certificate in that request.

Exp:
curl --cacert CERTIFICATE.cert GET "URL".

Obviously, you can edit the request to have your desired request.