# Use self signed certificate with cURL?

Tags: ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

I have a flask application running using a self signed certificate. I'm able to send in a curl request using:

```
curl -v -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"data":"value1","key":"value2"}' https://<server_ip>:<port>
```

The verbose logs show that everything went alright.

I wanted to avoid using the -k (--insecure) option and instead specify a .pem file that curl could use. Looking at the curl man page I found that you could do this using the --cert option.
So I created a .pem file using this:

```
openssl rsa -in server.key -text > private.pem
```

CURL throws me this error when using the private.pem file:

```
curl: (58) unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)
```

Any suggestions? - or is this only possible with a properly signed certificate?

Tnx

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This is just another version of this question: [Using openssl to get the certificate from a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885785/using-openssl-to-get-the-certificate-from-a-server)

Or put more bluntly:

Using [curl --cert](http://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-E) is wrong, it is for client certificates.

First, get the the certs your server is using:

```
$ echo quit | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername server -connect server:443 > cacert.pem
```

(`-servername` is necessary for SNI so that you get the right virtual server's certificate back)

Then make your curl command line use that set to verify the server in subsequent operations:

```
$ curl --cacert cacert.pem https://server/ [and the rest]
```

## special teaser

Starting with curl 7.88.0 (to be shipped in February 2023), curl can save the certificates itself with the new `%{certs}` variable for the [-w option](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/verbose/writeout). Blogged about [here](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2022/12/28/curl-w-certs/).

Comment: I've tried doing this but I still get the same error: `curl: (58) unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)`. I followed these instructions to generate my self-signed client and server certificates: http://dst.lbl.gov/~boverhof/openssl_certs.html. What else could I be doing wrong?

Comment: This adds other output to cacert.pem. You can use this command line instead: ´openssl s_client -showcerts -servername server -connect server:443 < /dev/null | sed -n -e '/BEGIN\ CERTIFICATE/,/END\ CERTIFICATE/ p' > server.pem´

Comment: ...also openssl should be told to "quit" to avoid hanging (and causing a "Bad request" to the web server): `echo quit | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername server -connect server:443 > cacert.pem`

Comment: Note that -servername assumes the server supports SNI. Apache 1.x - 2.2 doesn't so omit the -servername param. https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/s_client.html

Comment: thanks for your post, it assist me to make request from https server through curl. below command is what i use
$ curl --cacert file-path.pem https://localhost:443

Comment: I'm trying this from a mac but it's not working very well.  should the resulting cacert.pem begin with `CONNECTED(00000003)---Certificate chain`?

Answer (score 2):

To make request from https server through curl. I make use of the steps below

- Step1:  Generate self signed certificate with below code at root of the project you want to make use of it.`openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -nodes`
- Step2: Fill the prompt with required details but when you get to Common name input localhost e.g `Common Name (eg, fully qualified host name) []:localhost`
- step3: When your openssl cert.pem & key.pem has being generated startup your server then in another terminal or command line run `curl --cacert cert.pem https://localhost:443`

Note: I use port 443 which is the default https port, you can make use of another port then make sure cert.pem file path is well referenced.