# curl SSL certificate error: verifcation failed

Tags: ssl, curl, https, ssl-certificate

Please help me understand why I cannot successfully curl this url via https:

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.5 with curl 7.22.0, libcurl 7.22.0 and OpenSSL 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.25

```
$ curl -v https://www.onevanilla.com/
* About to connect() to www.onevanilla.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 199.83.128.4... connected
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
* Closing connection #0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

So I try to manually get the cert:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.onevanilla.com:443 </dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/www.onevanilla.com.pem
```

and then:

```
$ curl -v --cacert /tmp/www.onevanilla.com.pem https://www.onevanilla.com
```

but I get the same result:

```
* About to connect() to www.onevanilla.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 199.83.128.4... connected
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /tmp/www.onevanilla.com.pem
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
* Closing connection #0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

I can verify the certificate with openssl:

```
$ openssl s_client -host www.onevanilla.com -port 443 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs
```

and this returns `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`

I've also run `sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh` just to be sure, but no luck.

So it seems to me like the cert is valid (not expired, hostname matches CN), but I can never get a successful response using curl (unless of course I use `-k` or `--insecure` options). Can someone please explain?

Comment: Also see [Use self signed certificate with cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611193/use-self-signed-certificate-with-curl)

Answer (score 4):

The curl `--cacert <cert>` option is used to specify a *certificate authority* to use to verify the server certificate.  The certificate you copied from the `s_client` output is the *server certificate*, and using it as as the `--cacert` argument fails because the server certifiate is not self-signed, but signed by a different certificate authority (in your case, Go Daddy).

Invoke curl with the **`--capath`** option to specify the trusted root CA(s). This is analogous to the `s_client` `-CApath <dir>` option.

```
$ curl -v --capath /etc/ssl/certs https://www.onevanilla.com
```

Answer (score 4):

You've run into a problem caused by a long standing issue where OpenSSL is not properly handling situations with multiple trust path. If you look into the [report from SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=onevanilla.com&s=199.83.134.4&latest) you'll see, that the server provides the following chain:

```
[0] /O=www.onevanilla.com/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=www.onevanilla.com SAN=DNS:www.onevanilla.com,DNS:onevanilla.com
[1] /C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority/serialNumber=07969287
[2] /C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
[3] /L=ValiCert Validation Network/O=ValiCert, Inc./OU=ValiCert Class 2 Policy Validation Authority/CN=http://www.valicert.com//emailAddress=info@valicert.com
```

Browsers have included a root certificate for `Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority` and thus can build a trust path with [0],[1] and the root certificate and thus they will ignore the certificates [2] and [3]. OpenSSL instead will ignore only certificate [3] because it is self-signed and therefore should not have been included in the chain at all. It will then attempt to verify the chain [0],[1],[2] and will fail because it does not find a root certificate signing [2]. It will not attempt to verify the shorter chain [0],[1] instead.

For more details about this problem see [Python Urllib2 SSL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804710/python-urllib2-ssl-error) and http://kriscience.blogspot.de/2013/03/supporting-trusted-but-untrusted.html and [the OpenSSL bug report](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2732&user=guest&pass=guest).

What you can do: get the missing certificate from https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/valicert_class2_root.crt and use it in the `--cacert` parameter.