# Heroku Postgres - suddenly appeared error

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have an app on Heroku which is already running 5 months.

Suddenly I saw today that the server is crashed with this error message:

no pg_hba.conf entry for host "", user "", database "", SSL off

I don't understand what went wrong cause it's worked fine yesterday and I didn't released a new version by two weeks.

I also tried to connect to the db from my local machine and it's worked properly.

I'll appreciate any help !

Comment: are host, user and database really empty in the message, or did you remove them for security reasons?

Comment: removed for security reasons

Comment: Same issue here. My app has been constantly running for a month, issue started less than 24 hours ago.

Comment: ditto, running on Elixir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is to set the DB credentials as environment variables in Heroku, and use them inside a config object like so:

[image]

I preferred to connect using the connection string because it's much more cleaner, but it's seems like this option is not working anymore.

Comment: Note that the credentials change overtime: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku You should use the credential String heroku provides if you're using Heroku's database

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My app runs 24/7, and at March 13th, 2021 around 1PM GMT-0600 your issue started occuring. My app could no longer connect to a Database.

The following 3 steps solved the issue (for me):

Add this environment variable in Heroku under config vars:`NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`.

**E.G:**
[image]

Make sure you have SSL `rejectUnauthorized` to `false`

**E.G (in Node.js):**

```
const client = new Client({connectionString: databaseConnectionString, ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }});
await client.connect();
```

Add this to the database connection string, Not to the actual environment variable: `?sslmode=require`

**E.G: (In Node.js)**

```
const databaseConnectionString= process.env.DATABASE_URL + "?sslmode=require";
new Client({connectionString: databaseConnectionString ... });
```

[Reference 1](https://help.heroku.com/DR0TTWWD/seeing-fatal-no-pg_hba-conf-entry-errors-in-postgres), heroku says SSL must be used in production & add sslmode=require programatically

[Reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61691212/nodejs-and-express-error-self-signed-certificate), after doing the above I was getting 'error self signed certificate', stackoverflow post helped solve the issue by adding the environment variable