# Firebase error.. Error: Failed to make request to https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/releases.json

Tags: reactjs, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I am deploying my React app to firebase hosting. when I create firebase init and select all options I am getting this error.

```
C:\Users\user\git\Apps\screem>firebase init

     ######## #### ########  ######## ########     ###     ######  ########
     ##        ##  ##     ## ##       ##     ##  ##   ##  ##       ##
     ######    ##  ########  ######   ########  #########  ######  ######
     ##        ##  ##    ##  ##       ##     ## ##     ##       ## ##
     ##       #### ##     ## ######## ########  ##     ##  ######  ########

You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

  C:\Users\user\git\Apps\screem

? Are you ready to proceed? Yes
? Which Firebase CLI features do you want to set up for this folder? Press Space to select features, then Enter to confi
rm your choices. Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites

=== Project Setup

First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add,
but for now we'll just set up a default project.

? Please select an option: Use an existing project
? Select a default Firebase project for this directory: screem-59e13 (screem)
i  Using project screem-59e13 (screem)

=== Hosting Setup

Your public directory is the folder (relative to your project directory) that
will contain Hosting assets to be uploaded with firebase deploy. If you
have a build process for your assets, use your build's output directory.

? What do you want to use as your public directory? build
? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
? Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? No

Error: Failed to make request to https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/releases.json
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It looks like the `firebase` command is having trouble loading some of the dynamic data it needs from `https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/releases.json`. If you rerun the command, do you get the same error? If so, can you check if you can open the URL directly in a browser?

Comment: I can access this link via browser its some sort. json.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure why the CLI would then fail on the same machine. I hope someone else spots the problem.

Answer (score 8):

In order to understand the root cause of the error, try running the Firebase init command with the debug option:

```
firebase init --debug
```

It is possible that the request fails due to a "**self-signed certificate in the certificate chain**". If so, you will see this error in the debug output and then you can refer to this StackOverflow question for ways to workaround or fix the issue: [nodejs - error self signed certificate in certificate chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45088006/nodejs-error-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain)

Answer (score 5):

Error: Failed to make request to `https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/releases.json`

to solve this problem run this command:

`firebase init --debug`

it will work 100%

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.
Run `npm install -g firebase-tools` before running the command `firebase init`.

Comment: For me it was fixed after only running **npm install -g firebase-tools** (which is weird, because it was already installed).

Answer (score 0):

Try re-login Firebase using the below command:

```
firebase login --reauth
```