# https.get not working to access a public API with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, api

I'm currently trying to access the JokeAPI using Node's module HTTPS, where below is my code:

```
const https = require('https');
let url = 'https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Any';
https.get(url, function (res) {
    console.log(res);
})
```

However, somehow I keep getting this error:

```
node:events:498
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1530:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:944:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:725:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:442:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
```

Is it because I don't have a server set up? I'm a beginner with JS and Node, so any help would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: I actually added 'process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0';' to the top of the code and it worked, but now I'm getting an 'undefined' for a response body. And I'm not sure why that is happening :(

Comment: As far as I can tell, the API's certificate is valid. What OS and what version of Node are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nodejs - error self signed certificate in certificate chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45088006/nodejs-error-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain)

Comment: I'm on a Windows, using Node v16.14.0

Comment: Ah thanks Phil! Adding the process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0'; to the javascript file worked, not too sure why this error happens even after reading through that post or what the whole thing is about.. lol

Comment: However, now I'm getting an 'undefined' for a response body. I'm not too sure what's causing this.

Comment: See the [example in the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#httpsgeturl-options-callback). You need to read the response stream

Answer (score 0):

My system does not show the `self signed certificate in certificate chain` error, but it sounds like you have a work-around for that.

> However, now I'm getting an 'undefined' for a response body. I'm not too sure what's causing this.

`https.get()` just sends the request and reads the headers.  It does not, by itself, read the whole response.  To do that, you need to listen for the `data` event on the `res` object.  Installing the listener for the `data` event will cause the stream to start reading data from the incoming request.  This data will not necessarily come all at once.  It can come broken into multiple `data` events so you would really need to accumulate all the data and then in the `end` event, you know you have all the data.  You can see a full example for how to implement that here in the `http.get()` [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httpgeturl-options-callback).

Here's a simpler version that will just show you what's in each `data` event.

```
const https = require('https');
let url = 'https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Any';
https.get(url, function(res) {
    res.on('data', data => {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
});
```

FYI, I no longer use plain `https.get()` because all the higher level libraries listed [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) are more convenient to use and all support promises which is generally an easier way to program with asynchronous requests.

My favorite library from that list is [got()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got), but you can choose whichever one you like the API and/or features for.  Here's an implementation using `got()`:

```
const got = require('got');
const url = 'https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Any';

got(url).json().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```