# AuthRetryableFetchError: self signed certificate in certificate chain with Supabase and Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, ssl-certificate

I'm receiving the following error with certificates when trying to fetch the user from Supabase inside `getServerSideProps` with Next.js:

```bash
AuthRetryableFetchError: request to https://[redacted].supabase.co/auth/v1/user failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at [redacted]/node_modules/@supabase/gotrue-js/dist/main/lib/fetch.js:30:16
```

This is a simplified version of my code for reference:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req, res }) => {
  const supabase = createServerSupabaseClient({ req, res });
  const { data: { user }, error } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

  if (error) console.error(error);

  return {
    props: {
      user,
    }
  }
};
```

I've already setup `yarn` and `npm` to both use the right certificate using `yarn config set cafile /path/to/certificate/file` and `npm config set cafile /path/to/certificate/file` respectively, but for some reason when Next.js tries to get this from the server side (Node.js) it fails, and I'm not sure what service I need to setup to tell it where the certificate is set?

There are a lot of similar questions out there, but I couldn't find any specifically about Next.js or hitting this issue in Node.js.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems to be possible to get around this issue with setting `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` in `env.local`, but if anyone knows how to fix the issue rather than avoid it I'd be interested still.

src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45088585/827129

Comment: Have you ever been able to resolve this? I'm getting the same error on a local supabase environment, since I switched from Docker Desktop to Colima. But setting `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` does not help.

Comment: @riccardolardi sadly not, I’ve not revisited this issue since my work around got me past it