# Understanding openssl. Where is the cert file?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I am using the command ...

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect reds-cluster-01:443
```

And I get the output:

```
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = RapidSSL TLS DV RSA Mixed SHA256 2020 CA-1
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.my-co-example.com
verify return:1
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=*.my-co-example.com
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=RapidSSL TLS DV RSA Mixed SHA256 2020 CA-1
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGnxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBZ
...
```

I assume that means somewhere on the filesystem of my server there would be a file somewhere that has the string ...

```
MIIGnxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBZ
```

... in it.  How can I find that file without having to execute something like?

```
sudo grep -sr MIIGnxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBZ /
```

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that means somewhere on the filesystem of my server there would be a file somewhere that has the string ...

This assumption is wrong. What you see is part of the server certificate, which need to be checked against a CA certificate located in the local trust store. The server certificate is typically not in the local trust store. See [SSL Certificate framework 101: How does the browser actually verify the validity of a given server certificate?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/ssl-certificate-framework-101-how-does-the-browser-actually-verify-the-validity) for more on certificates are checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can see more with "**[CURL -W CERTS](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2022/12/28/curl-w-certs/)**" from **[Daniel Stenberg](https://github.com/sponsors/bagder)** (also [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93747/daniel-stenberg)), which works on [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/) for the past 25+ years.

> When a client connects to a TLS server it gets sent one or more certificates during the handshake.
>
> Those certificates are verified by the client, to make sure that the server is indeed the right one: the server the client expects it to be; no impostor and no man in the middle etc.
>
> When such a server certificate is signed by a Certificate Authority (CA), that CA’s certificate is normally not sent by the server but the client is expected to have it already in its [CA store](https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html).

(So no file to check on the filesystem)

> Ever since the day SSL and TLS first showed up in the 1990s user have occasionally wanted to be able to save the certificates provided by the server in a TLS handshake.
>
> The [`openssl` tool has offered this ability](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27611319/6309) since along time and is actually one of my higher ranked stackoverflow answers.

Now (for `curl` 7.88.0,to be shipped in February 2023), Daniel proposes:

> Using the `–write-out` (`-w`) option and the new variables `%{certs}` and `%{num_certs}`, `curl` can now do what you want.
> Get the certificates from a server in PEM format:
>
> ```
> $ curl https://curl.se -w "%{certs}" -o /dev/null > cacert.pem
> $ curl --cacert cacert.pem https://curl.se/
> ```

That is easier to parse than the `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect` current alternative.